# How do you split up OSLogMessage parameters to avoid a line length violation with SwiftLint?

Tags: swift, swiftlint

I just installed SwiftLint and integrated it with Xcode. I'm trying to resolve a line length violation for the following line:

```swift
Log.persistence.debug("Initialized \(self.instances.value.count) instances of type \(CoreDataEntity.self, privacy: .public) from CoreData.")
```

SwiftLint shows:

> Line Length Violation: Line should be 120 characters or less: currently 152 characters (line_length)

I tried to resolve this by splitting up the message string using the `+`operator, but that did not work:

```swift
Log.persistence.error("Instances of type \(CoreDataEntity.self, privacy: .public) "
                      + "could not be initialized from CoreData.")
```

results in a compiler error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'OSLogMessage'

Of course I could just customize the SwiftLint rule to ignore interpolated strings (which would work), but I'd prefer to somehow split up the messages instead. Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [multiline string literal](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html#ID564). Break the string literal up into multiple lines and put a backslash character (`\`) at the end of a line when you don't want to include the line break in the string, like this:

```swift
Log.persistence.debug(
    """
    Initialized \(self.instances.value.count) instances \
    of type \(CoreDataEntity.self, privacy: .public) \
    from CoreData.
    """
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - that works! Unfortunately auto indentation does work with those literals, but anyway...